# Objective C SDK for Pubnub in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, pubnub

I have added the Objective C SDK in my swift folder structure.

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/PubNub

I am trying to add

`#import <PubNub/PubNub.h>`

in my bridging header file. It is not recognizing the PubNub at all.

Also, it throws the error are CocoaLumberJack

Any leads will be helpful !

Comment: Did you add the path to PubNub and Lumberjack to the Framework Search Paths in your target's Build Settings?

Comment: No, I didn't know that I have to add. I am new to this . I will check.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to the PubNub and Lumberjack frameworks to the **Framework Search Paths (FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS)** under the **Build Settings** for your target.

It should look something like this:

```
$(inherited)
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/PubNub
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/CocoaLumberjack
```

Comment: There is already  path defined, I am trying to add pubnub under the same folder. Trying access it , like all other projects added there. But, still no luck

Comment: So your search paths are ok and Xcode still cannot find it?

Comment: Yes. Because 3 other projects are included from that path already !

Comment: What about the header paths?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. The problem being, PubNub is supported only along with the CocoaPods installation.

Comment: Yes , it is solved, now I am able to include PubNub. Thanks for your help